# can anyone please let me know why the bootstrap drop down menu is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap framework and tried to replicate http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html 
can any one please tell me why the dropdown-menu is not working.
the drop down menu which works in the example is not working with my code and i have included proper styles and js ! and one other styles are working so thinking its not a prob with the style any help ll be greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> The first step</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
              <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
            </form>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<hr>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
      </footer
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

@bana close the footer close tag

Edit your Script Reference like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: he is using the google cdn for jquery .. so nothing wrong with that .

Comment: @Shail he missed http: in script  reference and mistyped footer close tag

Comment: @snowp please go through the reference at this page https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery  He is using cloud version of the jquery

Comment: I used the Script Reference you said  in my html page but its not working friend

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below online utility before and it has worked for me.  It is free and quick.  I created a sample dropdown menu and then examined the code to apply to my website.  Good luck.

[CSS Menu Maker](http://cssmenumaker.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use the css and js file the following way: Check Jsfiddle [Example with cloud hosted bootstrap css and js](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/T94nA/2/) 
Also you are using wrong version of Jquery in your page it has to be

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The html should like below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         body {
         padding-top: 60px;
         padding-bottom: 40px;
           }
        </style>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> The first step</title>
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
```

And in footer :

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```